# .exe file gives error when I try to run it

Tags: python, linux, flask, pyinstaller

I have a python-flask hangman game, that I tried to wrap into a single executable file using pyinstaller with the following command line:

`pyinstaller -w -F --add-data "templates:templates" --add-data "static:static" hangman.py`

It seemed to work fine, and created build, dist, as well as the .spec file However, when I try to run the executable, I get the following error:

```
flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py:800: UserWarning: SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS adds significant overhead and will be disabled by default in the future.  Set it to True to suppress this warning.
 * Serving Flask app "hangman" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "hangman.py", line 101, in <module>
  File "flask/app.py", line 990, in run
  File "werkzeug/serving.py", line 1012, in run_simple
  File "werkzeug/serving.py", line 956, in inner
  File "werkzeug/serving.py", line 807, in make_server
  File "werkzeug/serving.py", line 701, in __init__
  File "socketserver.py", line 452, in __init__
  File "http/server.py", line 138, in server_bind
  File "socketserver.py", line 466, in server_bind
OSError: [Errno 98] Address already in use
[46425] Failed to execute script 'hangman' due to unhandled exception!
```

I am relatively new to programming, so please don't mind any wrong use of technical terms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to turn off the reloader like this :

```
app.run(debug=True, use_reloader=False)
```

**[Edit]**
it seems like some other application is using the same port. Check it by

```
netstat -tulpn
```

To get more information, you can use also :

```
tasklist
```

When you got the pid, I'd suggest stop it manually

You can also kill it via command kill:

```
Taskkill /PID THE_PORT /F
```

Comment: It still gives the same error as before.

Comment: Check my update

Comment: Your solution was working when I ran it on windows. but since my application was running on Linux, I had to use `sudo kill -9 $(lsof -t -i:port)` It worked though. Thank you